# How to use xpra like xvfb-run?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, x11, xpra

`xvfb-run` allows me to open a display and run a graphical app and when the app finishes xvfb closes too.

for example

```
xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-args="-screen 0, 1920x1080x24" nw script.js
```

is there a way to do this with xpra and xdummy?

current it requires to run 2 commands:

- `xpra start :100` but only once
- `DISPLAY=:100 vglrun nw script.js`

basically I want to start the display, run my app, wait for it to close, close the display with a single command...

Answer (score 1):

```
xpra start :100 --start-child="your-command" --exit-with-children
```

Comment: can you please help on this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372433/why-xpra-html5-client-dont-show-clients-local-printer-and-regular-xpra-desktop