# Why xpra html5 client don't show client's local printer and regular xpra desktop client does?

Tags: x11, python, lubuntu, xpra

I'm using xpra on lubuntu16.04 , I used  below command to start xpra

```
xpra start :5007 --start-child=leafpad --html=on --bind-tcp=0.0.0.0:44444 -d printing --encoding=jpeg
```

After starting xpra, when I connect from chrome using 192.168.x.x:44444 ip in urlbar, leafpad application shows on chrome tab but when I press ctrl + p on same tab it shows list of default  printers of lubuntu16.04 machine but don't show printers  of my machine

also when I tried to connect using simple xpra desktop client from my windows machine with 192.168.x.x:44444 ip , leafpad opens with new window on my windows desktop & on press of ctrl + p it shows my local windows machine printers as expected.

***So my question why in webbrowser (html5 client) cant show local machine printer and why xpra desktop client shows its , what is difference between this two html5 client and xpra desktop client?***

**Can any one explain if i want to list client's local printer in html5 client than what are necessary steps for it ?**

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 client uses the Javascript API which does not expose anything about printers available on the client. The way the HTML5 xpra client handles printing is by sending a PDF file to the browser.
The xpra server should have configured a "default" PDF printer for your HTML5 client.
If that's not the case, then please file a bug as per [reporting bugs](https://github.com/Xpra-org/xpra/wiki/Reporting-Bugs) and make sure to include full version details and the server log file with "-d printing" debug enabled.

Comment: ok noted. But can you tell me that how xpra client(windows specially) lists client's printer in xpra server for that socket connection..? I am just curious to know that without installing python on windows how xpra client works. It would be very helpfull to know how its work.

Comment: I don't understand the question, you are asking now. Which is a different question from your original one.

Comment: hi @totaam can you come in chat room for discussion here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61687/xpra , i will explain you my scenario !

Comment: No, there is an xpra IRC channel and a mailing list, and a bug tracker.